# HTML table cell resizes when a content is resizing

Tags: html, html-table, cell

Here's the [jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MNPGV/17/)

Here's the code :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td00" rowspan="2">
        <textarea>A very1 </textarea>
    </td>
    <td id="td01"> 
        <textarea>A very2 </textarea>
    </td>        
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--td>
        <textarea>A very3 </textarea>
    </td-->
    <td>
        <textarea>A very4 </textarea>
    </td>        
  </tr>
</table>
```

The css :

```
table, td
{ 
  border:1px solid black;  
}

table 
{
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
#td01, #td00 
{
  height:100%;
}
```

When I am changing the textarea inside cell with row = 0 and col = 0 the cell with row = 1 and col 1 is changing too.

I need fixing size of cells.

Comment: why not just give a size to the tds? eg `td {width:50%;}`

Comment: if you set `textarea{resize: none}` the cells aren't going to resize ever. that's the quick and dirty way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect, but i think it will do what you want, you have to set an fixed position to the td and a fixed height so i don't know if you'r ok with that for your project.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="td00" rowspan="2">
            <textarea>A very1 </textarea>
        </td>
        <td id="td01"> 
            <textarea>A very2 </textarea>
        </td>        
    </tr>
    <tr style="position:fixed;">
        <!--td>
            <textarea>A very3 </textarea>
        </td-->
        <td >
            <textarea>A very4 </textarea>
        </td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
   table, td{ 
    border:1px solid black;  
}

table {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
#td01
{
    height:320px;
}
```

EXAMPLE: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aAKAf/)